# I am getting invalid keyword argument while posting product array in customer order. What should i do?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

First i was getting an error like to create an explicit create method while serializing an array of product. So i added it but stiil im getting thhis error :

TypeError: 'customerorder' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

This is my serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class CustOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    price = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='price', queryset=Price.objects.all())
    # product = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='product', queryset=Product.objects.all())
    area = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='address', queryset=Area.objects.all())
    city = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='city', queryset=City.objects.all())
    product = ProductSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustOrder
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product = validated_data.pop('product')
        customerorder = CustOrder.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for product in product:
            Product.objects.create(**product, customerorder= customerorder)
        return customerorder
```

This is models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True))
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.product)

class CustOrder(models.Model):
    Customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    CustomerName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True, null= True, unique= True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    phone = PhoneField(null=False, blank=True, unique=True)
    landmark = models.PointField()
    #landmark = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter the landmark", default='Enter landmark')
    houseno = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES,default='Boneless chicken')
    # product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='custorder_productid')
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True,related_name='pricetag')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # price_id = models.ForeignKey(Price)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,related_name='pricetag')
    #price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=5, default=48.9)
    pay_method = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, default='RAZOR PAY')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    # Price.objects.aggregate(Sum('price'))

    def __str__(self):
         return self.CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors here.

Firstly for some reason you've set the related name from Product back to CustOrder as `pricetag`. That name does not appear to relate to either side of the relationship, so not sure why you've used it.

However even with that change, it still won't work, because you can't set many-to-many relationships at create time. You would need to create the product and then add it to the order.

But that *still* makes no sense, because you don't actually want to be *creating* products at all here; you want to add existing products to the order. So just do that:

```
    customerorder = CustOrder.objects.create(**validated_data)
    customerorder.product.add(*product)
```

Comment: But still it throws error:  TypeError: unhashable type: 'collections.OrderedDict'

Comment: Where does it throw that? You haven't got any reference to an ordered dict. Edit the question with the full traceback.

Comment: File "/home/neha/Documents/Order/ordering/serializers.py", line 45, in create
    customerorder.product.add(*product)
  File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 926, in add
    self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
  File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1066, in _add_items
    new_ids.add(obj)                                                                             **TypeError: unhashable type: 'collections.OrderedDict'**

Comment: customerorder.product.add(product)    And if i add this only then i get Type error unhashable type : list

Answer (score 0):

Your `Product` model has not field `customerorder`. That is the reason why Django raises the error.